# How to make a JavaScript To-Do list with keydown Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, keydown, removechild

I am attempting to make a JavaScript To-Do list app with an Array, push method, removeChild method, and a keydown function. I want the user to be able to use both the add button and the enter key to enter input. I succeeded in making an app that ultimately has 2 functions with 2 similar sets of variables and DOM methods: one for add button and another for keydown function (when the user hits enter after adding input). This setup seems to work fine. However, I would like to know if it is possible to create a ONE function that facilitates both the Add button AND the keydown function with one set of DOM methods. If so, could someone please provide a potential demo? Thanks!

(The following demo contains Bootstrap classes)

JS:

```
var array = [];

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
  array.push(task);
  var text = document.createTextNode(task);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "remove()");
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn-primary btn-sm newBtn");
  li.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(li);
}

function remove() {
  var task = this.event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  document.getElementById("myUl").removeChild(task);
}

document.getElementById("task").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var task2 = document.getElementById("task").value;
    array.push(task2);
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(task2);
    var li2 = document.createElement("li");
    var btn2 = document.createElement("button");
    btn2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
    btn2.setAttribute("onclick", "remove()");
    btn2.setAttribute("class", "btn-primary btn-sm newBtn");
    li2.appendChild(text2);
    li2.appendChild(btn2);
    document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(li2);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
  <input id="task" class="input-lg">
  <button id="inputBtn" class="btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="add()">add</button>
</div>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the necessary logic wrapped into a single `add()` function, why don't you just call it in your `keydown` event listener the same way you were calling it from your button's `onclick` listener?

```
document.getElementById("task").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    add();
  }
});
```

As a side note, the way you wrote your code, you didn't have to name your `btn2`/ `task2`/etc variables distinctly from `btn`/`task`/etc - they are only visible inside their functions' scopes. Inside the `{ }` that is.
Anyway, here's a working snippet:

```js
var array = [];

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
  array.push(task);
  var text = document.createTextNode(task);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "remove()");
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn-primary btn-sm newBtn");
  li.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(li);
}

function remove() {
  var task = this.event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  document.getElementById("myUl").removeChild(task);
}

document.getElementById("task").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    add()
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <input id="task" class="input-lg">
  <button id="inputBtn" class="btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="add()">add</button>
</div>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
var array = [];

// add the event listeners.
document.querySelector("#inputBtn").addEventListener("click", createToDO);
document.querySelector("#task").addEventListener("keydown", createToDO);

function createToDO(e) {
    var eventNum = e.which; //grab the event number

    if (eventNum === 1 || eventNum === 13) { // checks for both the button press and enter
        var li = document.createElement("li"),
            btn = document.createElement("button"),
            task = document.getElementById("task").value,
            text = document.createTextNode(task);

        array.push(task);
        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Remove"));
        btn.addEventListener("click", remove);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "btn-primary btn-sm newBtn");
        li.appendChild(text);
        li.appendChild(btn);
        document.querySelector("#myUl").appendChild(li);
    }
}

function remove(e) {
    var task = e.target.parentElement;
    task.remove();
}
```

You don't need to add the click handler in the HTML. This solution adds the listeners via the JavaScript.

```
<div class="mainDiv">
        <input id="task" class="input-lg">
        <!-- <button id="inputBtn" class="btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="add()">add</button> -->
        <button id="inputBtn" class="btn-primary btn-lg">add</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUl"></ul>
```